# Confused on ordering of function calls and debugging

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to debug a function call in my JSP program and really confused on the ordering of how things worked.   I am using NetBeans.  When I run the project in debug mode, it goes into my **'$("#searchEFT").mouseup(function ()'** function and trace through all of it. 'searchEFT' is a button that I am using to access my servlet. When I process the page and then click the 'searchEFT' button, it hits the function call based on getting the right alert but doesn't trace in the debug.   Why is it doing that?  Is the first call of the function on load setting up the check when the user does the mouseclick?

This function is outside of the **'$(document).ready(function ()'** at the top and the function call is after the button declaration in the JSP.

EDIT:  here is the JSP code:

```
  <head>
        <script>

       $(document).ready(function () 
     {

          $(function () 
          {
            $("#CMDCreationDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
              });
          });

    }) ;  

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
      function confirmExit()
      {
        alert("Alert-- leaving this page.");
       }         


     function numbersonly(myfield, e, dec) {

        //function to check that only numeric values are entered
        var key;
        var keychar;

        if (window.event)
            key = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e)
            key = e.which;
        else
            return true;

        keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

        // control keys 
        if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) || (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27))
            return true;

        // numbers
        else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
            return true;

        // decimal point jump 
        else if (dec && (keychar == ".")) {
            myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();
            return false;
        } else
            return false;
    }


 </script>

</head>   

<body>
    <header>
        <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
        <div class="floatL appTTL">SAMS - EFT Schedule Number Search/Update Screen</div>
        <div id="navWrap">
            <nav class="floatR">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Search</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>

    <main class="mainWrapper">
        <form id="formID" method="POST" action="EFTscreen?action=searchEFT" >  
            <div class="commandcontainer">
              <div id="divBox">
                  <h1 class="formTTL">Please Enter Schedule Number/Contract Year or either Schedule
                      Status/Creation Date value</h1>


                  <label class="labelTTL">Schedule Number</label>
                  <label class="labelTTL3">Contract Year</label>
                  <label class="labelTTL3">Status</label>
                  <label class="labelTTL">Creation Date</label>

                  <br/>
                  <input id="CMDScheduleNumber" name="CMDScheduleNumber" type="number" class="textsmall" maxlength="5"
                         value="${ScheduleNum}" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/>
                  <input id="CMDContractYear" name="CMDContractYear" type="number" class="textsmall" maxlength="4"
                         value="${ContractYear}" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/>
                  <select size="1" id="CMDSchedStatus" name="CMDSchedStatus" class="combosmall">
                       <c:forEach items="${statusList}" var="current">
                          <option value="${current}"
                           <c:if test="${current == Status}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                                   >${current}</option>
                       </c:forEach>
                  </select> 
                  <input id="CMDCreationDate" name="CMDCreationDate" type="text" class="textsmall"
                         value="${CreationDate}" maxlength="10"/>
                  <br/>
                  <button id="searchEFT" class="btn smBtn">Search</button>

              </div>
                  <div id="divButton">
                      <button id="searchMEFTS" type="submit" formaction="EFTscreen?action=searchMEFTS&screen=mainEFT"
                        class="btn midBtn">Update Schedule Status</button>   

                      <button id="clearMenu" type="submit" formaction="EFTscreen?action=clearMenu"
                        class="btn midBtn Space">Return to Menu</button>   
                  </div>


              <div id="clear"></div>    

            </div>   

            <article class="divBoxdet">
                <fmt:formatNumber var="trdettotal" value="${detResults.getTOTAL_AMOUNT()}" pattern="$##,###,##0.00"/>

                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Schedule Number
                    <input id="txtScheduleNumber" type="number" class="textdet" 
                            value="${detResults.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" readonly/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Contract Year
                    <input id="txtContractYear" type="number" class="textdet" 
                           value="${detResults.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" readonly/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Date Created
                    <input id="txtCreationDate" type="text" class="textdet" 
                               value="${detResults.getCREATION_DATE()}"  readonly/>
                </label>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Num of Records
                    <input id="txtNumRecords" type="number" class="textdet" 
                            value="${detResults.getNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS()}" readonly/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Status
                    <br/>
                    <input id="txtStatus" type="text" class="textdet" 
                            value="${detResults.getSTATUS()}"  maxlength="2"/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Status Date
                    <input id="txtStatusDate" type="text" class="textdet" 
                            value="${detResults.getSTATUS_DATE()}" maxlength="10"/>
                </label>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Schedule Total
                    <input id="txtScheduleTotal" 
                           type="text" class="textdet" value="${trdettotal}" readonly/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Schedule Post Date
                    <input id="txtPostDate" type="text" class="textdet" 
                            value="${detResults.getSCHEDULE_POST_DATE()}" maxlength="10"/>
                </label>
                <label class="labelTTLdet floatL">
                    Reel Number
                    <input id="txtReelNumber" type="text" class="textdet" 
                           value="${detResults.getREEL_NUMBER()}" maxlength="8"/>
                </label>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                   <button id="pullMEFTD" 
                        class="btn largeBtn Space floatL">Update Schedule Payment Status</button>

                <script>
                    $("#searchEFT").mouseup(function ()
                    {

                        var Cmd_Sched_Number = $('#CMDScheduleNumber').val();
                        var schedLen = Cmd_Sched_Number.length;

                        //var Cmd_Contract_Year = document.getElementById("CMDContractYear").value;
                        var Cmd_Contract_Year = $('#CMDContractYear').val();
                        var yearLen = Cmd_Contract_Year.length;

                        //var Cmd_Status = document.getElementById("CMDSchedStatus").value;
                        var Cmd_Status = $('#CMDSchedStatus').val();
                        var statStr = Cmd_Status.replace(/\s/g, "");
                        var statLen = statStr.length;

                        //var Cmd_Creation_Date = document.getElementById("CMDCreationDate").value;
                        var Cmd_Creation_Date = $('#CMDCreationDate').val();
                        var createLen = Cmd_Creation_Date.length;


                     if ((schedLen > 0 && yearLen === 0) || (schedLen === 0 && yearLen > 0))
                        {
                            alert("Schedule Number and EFT Contract Year must be both populated");
                        }
                        ;

                      if ((statLen === 0) && (createLen === 0) && (schedLen === 0) && (yearLen === 0))

                        {
                            var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to pull all EFT schedule numbers?");
                            if (r === false)
                            {
                                alert("Please enter information in any of the command line fields");
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#formID').submit();
                            }
                        } ;

                  });  


                  $("#pullMEFTS").mouseup(function ()
                    {

                        var Det_Sched_Number = $('#txtScheduleNumber').val();
                        var detschedLen = Det_Sched_Number.length;

                        //var Cmd_Contract_Year = document.getElementById("CMDContractYear").value;
                        var Det_Contract_Year = $('#txtContractYear').val();
                        var detyearLen = Det.length;

                        var Det_Status = $('#txtStatus').val();             

                     if (detschedLen > 0)
                        {
                            alert("Schedule Number not found.  Please investigate");
                        }
                        ;

                      if ( holdStatus.matches("RP") ||
                           holdStatus.matches("VP") ||
                           holdStatus.matches("CP") )

                       {
                        alert("User can only update schedule number in NP status");
                       }


                  });    

                </script>

            </article>

       </form>         
    </main>

</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, especially without code. If you want a breakpoint in the mouseup handler then put a breakpoint in the mouseup handler?

Comment: I can get a breakpoint in debug mode of the function when the page loads but I don't understand why the breakpoint isn't occurring on the actual click down and up of the button. It is processing based on my alert messages.   I will update my question to include the JSP code.

Comment: You question is difficult to read/understand. Secondly, IMO NetBeans is junk. I use it daily at work and hate every minute of it. It does not handle well mixed environments which is likely why it is not tracing as expected.

Comment: Where specifically are you placing the breakpoint? (And why not just debug JS in the browser?)

Comment: I had the breakpoint on the ''$("#searchEFT").mouseup(function ()'  line.   Like I mentioned I know I hit the breakpoint when I load the page but nothing when I actually click the searchEFT button.   I can try the debug in the browser.  Maybe it is an issue with how debugging works in NetBeans.    Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
$("#searchEFT").mouseup(function ()
```

is the function call that *sets* the `mouseup` handler; it is not the mouseup handler itself.

If you want to break *inside* the mouseup handler then you need to set a breakpoint somewhere inside the handler function itself, e.g.,

```
// First executable line of the mouseup handler
var Cmd_Sched_Number = $('#CMDScheduleNumber').val();
```

Unrelated, but I would break up the handler function into *much* smaller pieces, roughly:

```
function getFormData() {
  return {
      number: $('#CMDScheduleNumber').val().trim(),
      year:   $('#CMDContractYear').val().trim(),
      status: $('#CMDSchedStatus').val().replace(/\s/g, '').trim(),
      date:   $('#CMDCreationDate').val().trim()
  };
}

function invalidNumberAndYear(formData) {
  return ((formData.number !== '') && (formData.year   === '')) ||
         ((formData.year   !== '') && (formData.number === ''));
}

function isPullAll(formData) {
  return formData.number === '' &&
         formData.year   === '' &&
         formData.status === '' &&
         formData.date   === '';
}

function searchEftMouseup(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = getFormData();

  if (invalidNumberAndYear(formData)) {
    alert('Schedule Number and EFT Contract Year must be both populated');
    return;
  }

  if (isPullAll(formData)) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to pull all EFT schedule numbers?')) {
      $('#formID').submit();
    } else {
      alert('Please enter information in any of the command line fields');
    }
  }
}

$('#searchEFT').on('mouseup', searchEftMouseup);
```

This allows small stuff to be thought about easily, and begins to reveal your validation needs, and suggests a shape for your remaining code.

(Most of which, btw, was not relevant to the question–it's good to post only the minimum amount necessary to help people understand the issue :)

Comment: Such a newb I am in this Java stuff.   While I couldn't get the line breakpoint to stop in NetBeans debugger session, when I use the debugger in the actual browser it does go inside on the mouse click.   Thanks for the help again

Comment: @hammerva This is not Java; this is JavaScript.